# Coq - Coercion of list nat

Tags: list, types, coq, coercion

I would like to do a coercion from the type `list nat` to the type `list bool`. I would think that this could be done in the following way:

```
From Coq Require Import Lists.List.

Definition nat_to_bool (n : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | 0 => true
  | _ => false
  end.

Definition list_nat_to_list_bool (l : list nat) : list bool :=
  map (fun n => (nat_to_bool n)) l.

Coercion list_nat_to_list_bool : list nat >-> list bool.
```

However, this doesn't work. It seems like there is a fundamental issue with using coercion on something of the form `list nat`. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html#classes) states that a class name must be a defined name. Neither `list nat` nor `list bool` are defined names - they are both applications. You must give the types between you want to define coercions a name as in:

```
From Coq Require Import Lists.List.

Definition nat_to_bool (n : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | 0 => true
  | _ => false
  end.

Definition list_nat := list nat.
Definition list_bool := list bool.

Definition list_nat_to_list_bool (l : list_nat) : list_bool :=
  map (fun n => (nat_to_bool n)) l.

Coercion list_nat_to_list_bool : list_nat >-> list_bool.
```

Please note that the coercion function must use these names - you can't write `list nat` instead of `list_nat`. Also the applications of the coercion must use the defined names as in:

```
Definition test : list_bool := (1 :: nil) : list_nat.
```

I *guess* this is so because coercions might be done at the syntactic level where type unifications would be difficult.

Comment: So, if I have a function `f` whose inputs are of type `list bool`, and I want to use coercion to pass objects of type `list nat` to it, I'd have to edit `f` so that its input type is `list_bool` instead? There isn't a way around this?

Comment: I am not an expert for coercions, but as far as I know and understand the documentation, that's how it is, yes.